# How to upload large files to mediawiki in an efficient way

Tags: file-upload, mediawiki

We have to upload a lot of virtual box images witch are between 1G and 6G.
So i would prefer to use ftp for upload and then include the files in mediawiki.

Is there a way to do this?

Currently I use a jailed ftp user who can upload to a folder and then use the [UploadLocal](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UploadLocal) extension to include the files.

But this works only for files smaller then around 1G. If we upload bigger files we get a timeout and even by setting execution_time of PHP to 3000s the including stops after about 60s with a 505 gateway time out (witch is also the only thing appearing in the logs).

So is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is best suited for programming questions. You could try http://superuser.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import files from shell using [maintenance/importImages.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php). Alternatively, upload by URL by flipping [$wgAllowCopyUploads](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowCopyUploads), [$wgAllowAsyncCopyUploads](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAllowAsyncCopyUploads) and friends (requires that [job queue be run using cronjobs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Job_queue)). Alternatively, decide if you need to upload these files into MediaWiki at all, because just linking to them might suffice.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about hosting the Files outside of the wiki, but we will miss the descriptions and tuff.